# JavaFX8 Accordion animation low framerate

Tags: java, performance, animation, javafx, frame-rate

I'm using an accordion-control which contains 2 TitledPanes. In the first pane there is an spreadsheet-view from [controlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) and in the second there is a standard TableView containing some custom controls. So when I open or close the second TitledPane (with the TableView) the animation's framerate is very low. But the other one's performance is okay.
What could I do to fix the animation's performance?